# Access Database Backup using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access

Hi I created a wpf application in C# using Access as the db. I am trying to create a backup where the user will click on the backup button and then the file explorer window will open so that the user can choose where they want to save their backup. I looked on the site and there are several topics on this but I did not see one where the file explorer was called. I know how to create a backup copy using the following:

```
     private void BackupDatabase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        File.Copy("Results_West.mdb", "Results_WestBak.mdb", true);
    }
```

The above works and saves the backup where the executable is located but I'm not sure how to call windows file explorer and then do the save where the user wants to like when you're saving other files. Any ideas on this would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: google c# save file dialog

Comment: @AndreasMüller Thanks I looked up the save dialog feature, my question would be adding that to my code. Would that need to be called, then the above code to make a db backup and the user navigates to where the db bak is currently and copies it and then saves it else where or using save file dialog will come up with the db backup filename already and then they just choose?

Comment: If you want to just have them select the folder where it will be stored, then you want to use the `FolderBrowserDialog` (its in the System.Windows.Forms namespace, you will have to add a reference).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `SaveFileDialog` located under the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace.

The SaveFileDialog doesn't actually do any saving work, it's just a dialog to help you get a destination file path.

SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() will show the dialog, and when the user closes the dialog (eg. by accepting or declining), it will return a nullable boolean value to indicate if the dialog was accepted, declined or cancelled.

If ShowDialog() returns true, you should have a file path (string) that you can use in your copy method.

I hope this helps you understand. I have attached some code to help.

```
public void BackupDatabase()
{
    // The relative or full path of the database that you want to copy
    string fileToBackup = "Results_West.mdb";

    // The directory the save file dialog opens by default
    // --- Optional ---
    string initialFilePath = @"C:\Backup";

    // Initialize the sfd
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog
    {
        Title = "Choose a destination for your backup.",
        Filter = "Microsoft Access File|*.mdb",
        // --- Optional ---
        InitialDirectory = initialFilePath,
    };

    // sfd.ShowDialog() returns a nullable bool
    // If it returns true, you should have enough information to work with.
    // We need to escape if the result is not true.
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() != true)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        // sfd.FileName is the full path that the user selected.
        // 3rd parameter (true) specifies overwrite
        File.Copy(fileToBackup, sfd.FileName, true);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Failed to copy file.
    }
}
```